# Numerical integration with scipy.integrate.trapz returns a result but scipy.integrate.simps does not

Tags: python, math, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate the following data numerically:

```
t,y
9.960000000000001e-05,8.334379999999999e-05
9.98e-05,0.000126125
0.0001,0.00018125
0.0001002,0.0002385
0.00010040000000000001,0.000289625
0.0001006,0.000347313
0.0001008,0.000391719
0.000101,0.00043284399999999994
0.00010120000000000001,0.000472375
0.00010140000000000001,0.000502469
0.00010160000000000002,0.000528594
0.00010180000000000001,0.000546219
0.000102,0.000569188
0.0001022,0.000584719
0.0001024,0.000593969
0.00010260000000000001,0.000607375
0.0001028,0.000618906
0.000103,0.000629344
0.0001032,0.000629344
0.0001034,0.000636313
0.00010360000000000001,0.0006374999999999999
0.0001038,0.000630375
0.00010400000000000001,0.00059875
0.0001042,0.00046825
0.0001044,0.000287344
0.00010460000000000002,0.000208594
0.0001048,0.000196094
0.000105,0.000172625
0.00010520000000000001,0.000134781
0.0001054,0.000115906
0.0001056,0.00010306300000000001
0.00010580000000000001,9.31563e-05
```

As shown below, I read this data set from a csv file. 
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.integrate import trapz, simps

root="my/root/dir"

df = pd.read_csv(root+r"simps.csv")
print(trapz(df["t"], df["y"]))
print(simps(df["t"], df["y"]))
```

trapz returns a value (-9.5865055e-10) while simps returns nan and the following error:

```
anaconda\path\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py:324: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  h0divh1 = h0 / h1
anaconda\path\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py:326: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  y[slice1]*hsum*hsum/hprod +
anaconda\path\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py:327: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
  y[slice2]*(2-h0divh1))
anaconda\path\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py:326: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
  y[slice1]*hsum*hsum/hprod +
```

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 4):

A very stupid mistake: I exchanged x and y. Simps requires y as a first argument